# How can you explain the solubility of BeF2?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I know that Be has a tendency to create bonds with an increase covalent character so I can tell that BeF<sub>2</sub> is more covalent than let's say MgF<sub>2</sub>. So why is BeF<sub>2</sub> soluble in water while MgF<sub>2</sub> is barely soluble ? Shouldn't the ionic compound be more soluble ? 
My guess is that the lattice enthalpy of BeF<sub>2</sub> is not as great as the enthalpies of the other fluorides so it can be break down with much more ease and the energy gained from hydration outweighs the energy needed to separate the ions.

Comment: Because sucrose (sugar) is also soluble in water, maybe?  Water can dissolve plenty of covalent compounds, especially those with polar bonds or having hydrogen-bonding capability with the water.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that for BeF<sub>2</sub> the hydration enthalpy of Be<sup>2+</sup> is really high (due to Be<sup>2+</sup> being a small cation and having a high charge density) so the energy required to break the lattice is smaller than that gained from hydration of Be<sup>2+</sup> while for something like MgF<sub>2</sub> the enthalpy of the lattice is greater than the energy you would get from hydration of Mg<sup>2+</sup>. In general when dealing with compounds of the group II with F<sup>-</sup> because of the small radius of F<sup>-</sup> the lattice enthalpy is great and only the hydration energy released by the hydration of Be<sup>2+</sup> outweigh it thus making BeF<sub>2</sub> soluble while all the other fluorides formed with the group II elements are quite insoluble in water